# Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. ImageAi Custom

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, imageai

I need help...
Im using imageai Custom Class to create my own detection...

And here we go

```
from imageai.Classification.Custom import ClassificationModelTrainer
model_trainer = ClassificationModelTrainer()
model_trainer.setModelTypeAsResNet50()
model_trainer.setDataDirectory("leads_test")

model_trainer.trainModel(num_objects=1, num_experiments=1, enhance_data=True, batch_size=1, show_network_summary=True)
```

<...>

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection

detector = ObjectDetection()
model_path = "leads_test/models/model_ex-001_acc-1.000000.h5"
input_path = "ECG/IMG_0239.jpg"
output_path = "./output/newimage.jpg"

detector.setModelTypeAsTinyYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(model_path)
detector.loadModel()
```

```
ValueError: Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. Model expected 24 layers, found 107 saved layers.
```

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be related with `tensorflow` or `keras`. If you're using an open-source package, you can try opening an issue in their repository.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I have to use `imageai.Classification.Custom import CustomImageClassification` instead o`f imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection`

```
from imageai.Classification.Custom import CustomImageClassification
prediction = CustomImageClassification()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet50()
prediction.setModelPath('leads_test/models/model_ex-001_acc-1.000000.h5')
prediction.setJsonPath('leads_test/json/model_class.json')
prediction.loadModel(num_objects=1)
```

The problem was in different model type while training and prediction.